# Can we configure ADFS for IDP initiated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I'm looking for ways of integrating ADFS as a IDP for a SAML2 service provider. I have already configured the SAML2 provider with the verification certificates etc. And we used "Add Relying Party Trust Wizard" to configure ADFS with the details of the SAML2 SP.

But I'm not sure about the rest of the workflow here. Appreciate if anyone can guide me to a good article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/09/27/ad-fs-2-0-relaystate/ and referenced articles for details

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does idpinitiatedsignon.aspx comes with ADFS itself or should we implement it in order to generate SAML request ?

Comment: It's inbuilt. Only needs to be manually enabled for windows 2016 via powershell. I don't know the os you have for adfs.